# Kernel modules folder doesn't match uname -r

Tags: kernel-modules, directory-structure

I have a fresh install of Arch Linux. I am unable to use `modprobe` to set up kernel modules. When I run `sudo modprobe r8169` (for example), I get the error `modprobe: FATAL: Module r8169 not found in directory /lib/modules/4.8.13-1-ARCH`.

Contents of `/lib/modules`:

```
$ ls -1 /lib/modules
4.10.8-1-ARCH
extramodules-4.10-ARCH
```

Result of `uname -r`:

```
$ uname -r
4.8.13-1-ARCH
```

Is it safe to simply rename the modules directory to match `uname -r`?

Comment: On further investigation, it appears this issue is caused by the installed version of the kernel (from `pacman`) is different from the version running. Should I delete this question?

Answer (score 2):

`/lib/modules` has a subdirectory for each kernel version that is installed. Evidently you've upgraded your kernel since you last rebooted; you're running 4.8.13-1 and you've upgraded to 4.10.8-1. Upgrading the kernel only takes effect when you reboot.

Modules must be loaded in the exact same kernel version, compiled with the same option. (There are exceptions but the module has to be designed carefully for that; modules that come with the kernel itself don't jump through the hoops that would allow them to work on a different kernel.)

As a consequence, you shouldn't remove a kernel version that's still running. Removing the file containing the running kernel is harmless — that file is only used at boot time — but removing the kernel package also removes the modules, and that means you can't load new drivers.

Another reason not to remove the running kernel version is that in case there's a bug in the new kernel you installed, having the old tested kernel guarantees that you'll still be able to boot. Obviously kernels get tested before they're distributed, but sometimes a hardware-specific bug can make it through the cracks.

Distributions with automated upgrade scripts normally take care not to remove the running kernel. I don't know how this works on Arch, but Arch is pretty hands-on so you should take care of this manually. You should still be able to load modules if you reinstall the right kernel version.